# Convergence in probability of Gaussian random variable sequence?

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $X_n\sim \mathcal N(0,\sigma^2_n)$ and that $\sigma_n^2$ is a sequence of positive real numbers that converges to $\sigma^2<\infty$ as $n\rightarrow\infty.$

I can show that $X_n\rightarrow X\sim \mathcal N(0,\sigma^2)$ in distribution. Intuitively, I feel we shouldn't have convergence in probability though, but I can't find a source that answers this question.

So I want to show that
$$P(|X_n-X|>\epsilon)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\left(\int_{-\infty}^{x-\epsilon}f_n(s)ds+\int_{x+\epsilon}^\infty f_n(s)ds\right) dx \ \overset{n\rightarrow\infty}{\longrightarrow} \ 0$$

where $f_n$ and $f$ is the normal distributions with variances $\sigma^2_n$ and $\sigma^2.$ Am I just making some mistake in the equation above? Can someone work this out directly carefully splitting up the integrals and bounding the functions appropriately so as to get an algebraic expression that goes to zero as $n$ goes to infinity?

Also, isn't $X_n-X\sim \mathcal N(0,\sigma_n^2+\sigma^2)?$ If this is ok, then, I can't make sense of convergence in probability here as it seems we shouldn't have it then.

**Question:** So, does $X_n \overset{P}{\longrightarrow} X$ or not? I'm hoping that I can see a *direct, low-level* proof either way.

E.g. to show $X_n \overset{d}{\longrightarrow} X$, what I consider low-level is
$$\begin{aligned}
|F_n(t)-F(t)| &\leq \int_{-\infty}^t|f_n(x)-f(x)|dx\\
&\cdots \\
&= 2\int_{0}^t|f_n(x)-f(x)|dx+\int^{\infty}_{t}|f_n(x)-f(x)|dx\\
&\cdots \\
&< \frac\epsilon2+\frac\epsilon2=\epsilon\\
\end{aligned}$$
where I have used symmetry and skipped many tedious steps here which included bounding $|f_n(x)-f(x)|$ in a few different ways, breaking up the intervals of integration a bit more, and lots of algebra. I am a bit too lazy at the moment to type it all out here (I guess I might if requested to do so). I did use a big O notation bound, which isn't really as low-level as I want since I'd really want to show that directly at an even lower-level, but that will suffice for now.

Comment: $X_n + X\sim \mathcal N(0,\sigma_n^2+\sigma^2)$  You have a sign error.

Comment: @DAdams. Are you sure about that? $Var(aX+ bY)= a^2 \text{Var}(X) + b^2\text{Var}(Y) +2ab\text{Cov}(X,Y)$. I was assuming independence, but forgot to state that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$X_n$ need not converge to $X$ in probability. For a simple (albeit somewhat contrived) example, consider the case where $X_n=-X$ for all $n$. Then $X_n$ has the same distribution as $X$, so certainly $X_n\to X$ in distribution, but $X-X_n=2X$ does not converge to zero in probability.

Comment: That's what what I figured. What about $\sigma_n^2=\sigma^2(1-1/n)$ and all are independent?

Comment: If $\{X_n\}$ converges in probability then $X_n$ and $X_m$ are close to each other with high probability for $m,n$ large. This will not be the case if $X_n$ and $X_m$ are independent Gaussians.

Comment: Ok. That solves my problem and confirms my intuition. Thanks!